# Is there any way to get Jenkins artifacts in Gitlab pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab-ci, artifact, gitlab-pages

Basically the opposite of this question: [Is there any way to get Gitlab pipeline artifacts in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767736/is-there-any-way-to-get-gitlab-pipeline-artifacts-in-jenkins)

My project is built on Jenkins. It generates a JavaDoc.
I want to publish this JavaDoc as a Gitlab Pages.

So I would need my gitlab-yml to be able to retrieve the produced javadoc from Jenkins.

Alternatively, my artifacts are stored on a network drive, so an access to this network drive would work too

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am stuck at the point that I don't even have a page at the moment. My experience with gitlab ci is 0

Comment: As far as I see, you need a Gitlab repository to build these pages from. Then why not use the whole power of Gitlab CI and also build your project there?

Comment: thank you but I am not looking to rework my entire company CI/CD so this is out of purpose. We host our repositories and doc on gitlab, build on jenkins, package on conan.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this plugin could be helpful to you...

There is a plugin called Archived Artifact Url Viewer. It seems to be like you needs.

"Jenkins plugin to view contents of a file inside a zip or jar file under a subdirectory of artifacts directory of a build The url to access a file inside a zip or jar archive within the artifact folder of a build is as follows"

```
/archivedArtifacts/artifact/<job_name>/<build_number/<relative location of zip or jarfile within artifact folder>/<location of file within archive>
```

Ex:

```
http://<jenkins_url>/archivedArtifacts/artifact/Build%20-%20Dev/10526/junit-logs.zip/junit.log
```

https://plugins.jenkins.io/archived-artifact-url-viewer/