# How to migrate Jenkins Artifacts file to Gitlab

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, artifacts

I am building a python script in Jenkins using pipeline job. The output file is an excel file which is saved in Jenkins as an artifact. Is there a way to store this artifact file automatically in Gitlab project?

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60416768/is-there-any-way-to-get-jenkins-artifacts-in-gitlab-pipeline

Comment: This is an open issue, please check here https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issues/486